# Too slow while reading and writing content cell by cell

Tags: c#, performance, xls

I have developed an application which read 32 xls file and write their content into one excel file. Program is running fine but it's too slow(taking 20-25 mins in case of 32 files) because I am reading and writing cell by cell. Is there any way I can make it more fast. In my case each cell has different format,font,border and so on. Can I read whole content at a time with format and paste it into the resultant file.I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel API. Here is my code that I am using

```
Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            // data member initialization for reading the sheet
            Excel.Application app;
            Excel.Workbook workbook;
            Excel.Worksheet worksheet;
            Excel.Range range;

            // data member initialization for writing sheet
            Excel.Application finalApp;
            Excel.Workbook finalWorkBook;
            Excel.Worksheet finalWorkSheet;

            String path = this.textBox1.Text;
            String numberOfFiles = (String)this.comboBox1.SelectedItem;
            int count = 1;
            int row = 1, col = 2;
            int startingrowIndex = 1;
            int endingrowIndex = 1;
            int valueCount = 1;
            string value = textBox2.Text;
            try
            {
                // Object creation for the final sheet
                finalApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
                finalApp.Visible = true;
                finalWorkBook = finalApp.Workbooks.Add(1);
                finalWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)finalWorkBook.Sheets[1];


                // opening a excel file
                app = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
                Excel.Borders b=null;
                Excel.Borders fb = null;
                try
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < Int32.Parse(numberOfFiles); k++)
                    {
                        fullPath = @path + @"\" + count + ".xls";
                        workbook = app.Workbooks.Open(fullPath, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
                            Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value
                            , Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
                            Missing.Value);
                        worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets.get_Item(1);
                        range = worksheet.UsedRange;
                        int cnum1 = range.Columns.Count;
                        int rnum1 = range.Rows.Count;
                        int i, j;
                        for (i = 1; i <= rnum1; i++)
                        {
                            for (j = 1; j <= cnum1; j++)
                            {
                                if ((range.Cells[i, j] as Excel.Range).Value2 != null)
                                {
                                    string value1 = (range.Cells[i, j] as Excel.Range).Value2.ToString();
                                    finalWorkSheet.Cells[row, col] = value1;
                                }
                                b = (Excel.Borders)(range.Cells[i, j] as Excel.Range).Borders;
                                fb = (finalWorkSheet.Cells[row, col] as Excel.Range).Borders;

                                fb[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom].Weight = b[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom].Weight;
                                fb[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeTop].Weight = b[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeTop].Weight;
                                fb[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeLeft].Weight = b[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeLeft].Weight;
                                fb[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight].Weight = b[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight].Weight;

                                fb[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom].LineStyle = b[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom].LineStyle;
                                fb[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeTop].LineStyle = b[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeTop].LineStyle;
                                fb[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeLeft].LineStyle = b[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeLeft].LineStyle;
                                fb[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight].LineStyle = b[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeRight].LineStyle;
                                (finalWorkSheet.Cells[row, col] as Excel.Range).Interior.Color = (range.Cells[i, j] as Excel.Range).Interior.Color;
                                (finalWorkSheet.Cells[row, col] as Excel.Range).Font.Color = (range.Cells[i, j] as Excel.Range).Font.Color;

                                (finalWorkSheet.Cells[row, col] as Excel.Range).Interior.PatternColor = (range.Cells[i, j] as Excel.Range).Interior.PatternColor;
                                (finalWorkSheet.Cells[row, col] as Excel.Range).Interior.Pattern = (Excel.XlPattern)(range.Cells[i, j] as Excel.Range).Interior.Pattern;
                                (finalWorkSheet.Cells[row, col] as Excel.Range).WrapText =(range.Cells[i, j] as Excel.Range).WrapText;
                                col++;
                            }
                            row++;
                            col = 2;
                        }
                        //finalWorkBook.SaveAs("hello.xlsx", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlExcel4Workbook, Missing.Value,
                        //Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
                        //Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
                        endingrowIndex = row-1;
                        finalWorkSheet.Cells[startingrowIndex,1]=value+valueCount;
                        (finalWorkSheet.Cells[startingrowIndex, 1] as Excel.Range).VerticalAlignment = Excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter;
                        (finalWorkSheet.Cells[startingrowIndex, 1] as Excel.Range).HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
                        (finalWorkSheet.Cells[startingrowIndex, 1] as Excel.Range).WrapText = true;
                        finalWorkSheet.get_Range(finalWorkSheet.Cells[startingrowIndex, 1], finalWorkSheet.Cells[endingrowIndex, 1]).Merge(Type.Missing);
                        startingrowIndex = row + 1;
                        workbook.Close(false, false, Missing.Value);
                        count++;
                        row++;
                        col = 2;
                        valueCount++;
                    }
                    Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
                    MessageBox.Show("Successfully Completed");
                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe)
                {
                    Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
                    MessageBox.Show("Error while opening the file "+fullPath);
                }
                //finalWorkBook.Close(true,false,Missing.Value);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
                MessageBox.Show(@"Some Error has occurred.Please check the path Correctly
                whether it's correct or try again");
            }
        }
```

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: How about you write in some code to output to a log at various times throughout your program and find out what parts of your code are taking a long time to execute? Once you figure that out, you should try to figure out why, and if you cannot, post that section in a new question here.

Comment: I have done that it's taking time because Data in the excel files are too much and my program copy the content of each cell and paste it into the resultant file.After that read the format of the same cell and apply the same in the resultant file cell. It does so for every cell.That's why it's slow

Comment: Why can't you take all used rows and write them to the new file starting at a certain position?

Comment: @wonko79 I can do that but what about the formatting of the cells. Each cell has different formatting then also I have to go to each cell and copy an paste the formatting. I don't know whether I can copy the formatting of more than one cells simultaneously or not.If yes, please tell me how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Copy a range of a loaded xls to the clipboart using range.copy. Then paste the clipboart contents to the new xls with [range.PasteSpecial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.pastespecial.aspx). There you can state what is copied to which range in the new sheet.

Comment: @wonko........ I had done that first......... but in that case if I copy and paste something during the running of a program........ then program terminate...........because of usage of clipboard area which is used by both me and my program...